# Derivatives questions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, maxima-minima

I faced some problems which were strange to me. I didn't know how to approach them at all.

Question 1: [image: First Question]

Question 2: [image: Question 2]

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For the second one, I suggest you try graphing the tangent lines and then trying to fit in a curve to see what happens.

Comment: That's okay if you could help me with question 1.

Comment: Just study and [read this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBfSwZAUoJM)